# Php view execl and xls file on browser

Tags: php

I would like to display an `execl` file within my browser similar to how a PDF file is viewed.Is there any way to accomplish this. I have already used an `execl library`, but this does not fulfil my requirements. 
Here is example I would like to used in excel but its not working

`header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename . '"');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');`

I also used PHPExcel library for viewing execl file on browser but its not working

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems -- but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: @waka thank for the response I have tried alot things that why I am posting here ..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8906202/displaying-excel-file-in-a-browser-phpexcel This trend might help

Comment: Thank @belgarath for the response I try that code its also not wokring ..

Comment: For the sake of those of us who are too stupid to know what you mean; can you explain "not working"? When you run that script, does it show any errors (or write them to the log),? Does it crash your server? Does it download the file rather than display it in the browser? Does it output incorrect data?

Comment: And if you want to display the Excel fiel in the browser, why are you trying to display a PDF? Why don't you just use PHPExcel's HTML Writer and display that output in the browser?